Can not add library from Github
I try to add Youtube Extractor library from Github but I cannot add library. For example, I add this library:
implementation("com.github.wizzeal:YouTubeExtractor:1.0")

In MainActivity:
import com.wizzeal.youtubeextractor.YoutubeExtractor;

It gives error:
Cannot resolve symbol 'wizzeal'

I tried many libraries, but the same error occurs. I am currently using Android Studio Koala.
I also tried clearing the cache and rebuilding the project, but the error still occurs.

It seems a package like that does not exist on Maven, can you share the source or a github page you found the library at?

the closest I've found is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.Commit451/YouTubeExtractor, may that be it?

A quick search for the lib, specifically wizzeal, doesn't bring up anything. Is it in a private repository? Maybe you could provide more details on how you add the dependency

If you want to use a dependency from GitHub, you need to add:
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } 

to your repositories, for example:
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // this line
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

However, keep in mind that your provided library may not be still available due to JCenter's discontinuation in February 2021. If the library is not available through JitPack, you might consider adding:
maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter' }

to access old JCenter repositories as an alternative repository (I tried with your provided library com.github.wizzeal:YouTubeExtractor:1.0, it worked).
Warning: However, you should only do this if you really need the library, as it may pose security risks. Always prioritize trusted sources to ensure the safety of your project.
